# How to show error message when maximum limit exceed in text area field?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

How to show error message when maximum limit exceed in text area field?.i had wrote the script,its allowing 1000 characters.its ok to me.at the same time need to show error message"text will not allow 1000 characters."

```
<textarea  maxlength="1000" id="text" rows="4" cols="90" ></textarea>  


    function maxLength(el) {    
    if (!('maxLength' in el)) {
        var max = el.attributes.maxLength.value;
        el.onkeypress = function () {
            if (this.value.length >= max) return false;
        };
    }
}

maxLength(document.getElementById("text"));
```

can anybody help me on this.

Comment: you can just use a span with color red, initially set that span display to none if limit exceed then set display block and display the error. If it is less than 1000 character then don't show

Comment: Or you could show how  many character remaining like this http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/ysC7L/

Comment: when he fill 1000 characters after when he enter the 1001 value it will not allow at that time i need show error " text will not allow 1000 characters."

Answer (score 1):

```
 <textarea  maxlength="1000" id="text" rows="4" cols="90" ></textarea>  
                    <span id="errMsg"></span>
<script>
 $(document).ready( function() {        
    var maxLen = 1000;

    $('#text').keypress(function(event){
        var Length = $("#text").val().length;
        var AmountLeft = maxLen - Length;
        $('#txt-length-left').html(AmountLeft);
        if(Length >= maxLen){
            if (event.which != 8) {
                    $('#errMsg').text('text will not allow 1000 characters.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

 });

 </script>
```

Comment: alert is not working.i need show error message only.no need to put alert.

Comment: alert is not working.i need show error message only.no need to put alert.

Comment: then you can add one label or span besides your text-area and you can show message in that label or span.

Comment: check i edited the answer. this might help you.

Comment: its not worked patelkiran. its ending 1000 characters after its not showing error message.can you help me on this.

Comment: hey i just edited my answer with working javascript function. check now its working for me just tested. can you try once.

Comment: its working now.thanks for your answer patelkiran.

Answer (score 1):

you can limit textarea and at the same time to show error.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=JavaScript>

function check_length(my_form)
{
   maxLen = 1000; 
   if (my_form.my_text.value.length >= maxLen)
    {
        var msg = "You have reached your maximum limit of characters allowed";
        alert(msg);

    }

}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name=my_form method=post>
<textarea onKeyPress=check_length(this.form); onKeyDown=check_length(this.form); 
 name=my_text rows=4 cols=30></textarea>


</form>

</body>
</html>

Regards Ajay
```